# Add react-grid-layout tag

Tags: discussion, support

I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294793/react-grid-layout-sidebar-dragdrop) that relates to react-grid-layout library (https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout), but I won't get an answer if it isn't tagged with react or react-grid-layout. I don't have 1500 reputation points, can this tag be added?

Comment: [status-completed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)? :)

Comment: Appreciated @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: ... I don't understand your request. Why didn't you add the [tag:reactjs]? Also why isn't your question tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: I have (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297736/react-grid-layout-drag-drop-emulation)